# Is there a downside to a signed kernel?

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, secure-boot

Mostly a general linux question, but where it needs to be specific I am referencing Debian 12 Bookworm amd64 UEFI booting through grub(not direct kernel stub).
I have secure boot disabled in firmware for some multiboot reasons and I have options for signed or unsigned kernels.

- Are there any negative impacts of a signed kernel, possible incompatibilities or failures to load modules?
- The signed kernel is about 2% larger which is insignificant for my system.
  Do use the same modules or require separate special builds?
- Can I have a signed and and an unsigned one the system at the same time, similar to having an older stable and very new kernel of the same series, or regular and real-time kernels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Secure Boot is disabled, the signature on a signed kernel isn’t used, and it behaves like an unsigned kernel.

1. There are no incompatibilities, and you can load modules without signing them.
2. See above, no special build is required.
3. Yes, you can have unsigned kernels alongside signed kernels.